# Display logo in rdlc report header from database in wpf Using Parameter

Tags: c#, wpf

Code:

```
private bool _isReportViewerLoaded;

private void reportViewer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!_isReportViewerLoaded)
    {
        Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource reportDataSource1 = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource();
        SellMechDataSet dataset = new SellMechDataSet();
        dataset.BeginInit();
        reportDataSource1.Name = "DataSet2";
        //Name of the report dataset in our .RDLC file
        reportDataSource1.Value = dataset.tblLogo;
        this.reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource1);
        this.reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = "D:\\17-6-2016\\ShellMechProject\\demo\\Reports\\CustomerList.rdlc ";
        dataset.EndInit();
        //fill data into WpfApplication4DataSet
        SellMechDataSetTableAdapters.tblLogoTableAdapter accountsTableAdapter = new SellMechDataSetTableAdapters.tblLogoTableAdapter();
        accountsTableAdapter.ClearBeforeFill = true;
        accountsTableAdapter.Fill(dataset.tblLogo);
        string ImagePath = "";

        if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            con.Open();
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblLogo", con);
            SqlDataReader dr;
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                ImagePath = dr["ImagePath"].ToString();

            }
        }
        ReportParameter rp = new ReportParameter("Path", ImagePath);
        rp.Name = "Path";
        //rp.Values = ImagePath;
        reportViewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { rp });
        reportViewer.RefreshReport();
        _isReportViewerLoaded = true;
    }
}
```

Design:

```xml
<Window x:Class="demo.Reports.CustomerList"
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
       xmlns:col="clr-namespace:System.Collections;assembly=mscorlib"
       xmlns:rv="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms;assembly=Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms" 
       Icon="/img\F_Logo.png"
       WindowStyle="None"
       ShowInTaskbar="False"
       Title="Customer Report" Height="742.955" Width="1140.164"  WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner" ResizeMode="NoResize"  Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid Margin="-1,2,1,-172"  Background="#d9f9f7" Height="913" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Label Content="Customer Report" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="25" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ActiveCaptionBrushKey}}" Margin="-1,-2,0.2,0"></Label>
        <Button Content="X" Name="btnExit"  Grid.Row="0" Height="20" Width="20" FontFamily="Times New Roman" Foreground="Red" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="18" Margin="1118,0,2,893" RenderTransformOrigin="4.564,0.572" Click="btnExit_Click"  />
        <Grid Margin="0,23,0,-23">
            <WindowsFormsHost Name="windowsFormsHost1">
                <rv:ReportViewer x:Name="reportViewer" Load="reportViewer_Load" />
            </WindowsFormsHost>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I am fetching path from database and display it into image control 
but error occur

> An error occurred during local report processing.

If any other option are available in wpf report logo.

Answer (score 1):

`EnableExternalImages` has to be set to True, otherwise the image will not be shown,also make sure your image path is valid. Also in the properties of the image control in `RDLC` report under General category make sure that you've set `select the image source` to `External` and value inside `Use this image` to the expression `=Parameters!Path.Value`

```
reportViewer.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

When adding parameters to the ReportViewer and you get

> An error occurred during local report processing.

then always look the the `InnerException` message. That could be anything, e.g. the DataSet name inside the Report need to match to the name in CodeBehind.

I have tried the issue and was also not successful using `External` and `=Parameters!Path.Value`.

So the code below is a workaround. The first image is not the table header. I had to delete the table header and placed a single image above the table. I was not able to manage reading from to two different DataSets for one table, reading the from the second DataSet for the header and use the first DataSet for the data rows.

In the Report for `Select the image source` `Database` got selected and for the single image in `Use this field` `=First(Fields!Image.Value, "DataSet2")`. For the table with the 3 pictures I just use the field. You need to select a MIME type, but my experience was that it don't really need to match the real image type.

[image]

```
class ReportPhoto
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public byte[] Photo { get; set; }

    public ReportPhoto()
    {
    }

    public ReportPhoto(string theFilename, FileInfo thePhotoFile)
    {
        FileName = theFilename;
        Photo = File.ReadAllBytes(thePhotoFile.FullName);
    }
}


class HeaderImage
{
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }

    public HeaderImage()
    {
    }

    public HeaderImage(FileInfo theImageFile)
    {
        Image = File.ReadAllBytes(theImageFile.FullName);
    }
}


public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private List<ReportPhoto> _ReportPhotos;
    private List<HeaderImage> _HeaderImages;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _ReportPhotos = new List<ReportPhoto>();
        _HeaderImages = new List<HeaderImage>();    


        _ReportPhotos.Add(new ReportPhoto("homer.bmp", new FileInfo(@"C:\homer.bmp")));
        _ReportPhotos.Add(new ReportPhoto("lisa.bmp", new FileInfo(@"C:\lisa.bmp")));
        _ReportPhotos.Add(new ReportPhoto("mag.bmp", new FileInfo(@"C:\mag.bmp")));
        _HeaderImages.Add(new HeaderImage(new FileInfo(@"C:\TheSimpsons.png")));

        FillReport();
    }

    private void FillReport()
    {
        _ReportViewer.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "ReportViewerTest2.Report1.rdlc";
        PermissionSet permissions = new PermissionSet(PermissionState.Unrestricted);
        _ReportViewer.LocalReport.SetBasePermissionsForSandboxAppDomain(permissions);

        Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource reportDataSource = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource("DataSet1", _ReportPhotos);
        Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource reportDataSource2 = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource("DataSet2", _HeaderImages);
        _ReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
        _ReportViewer.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = true;
        _ReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource);
        _ReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource2);
        _ReportViewer.LocalReport.Refresh();

        _ReportViewer.LocalReport.Refresh();
        _ReportViewer.RefreshReport();
    }
}
```

Comment: i want image from database

Comment: Changing to your code with the data from your database `ImagePath = dr["ImagePath"].ToString();` should not be this difficult. You are loading a file from a path, with the path given from the database. In my example the path is fix in the code. So what is the problem to adapt this? My suggestion is not to assign the path to the report. Just load it before to a byte array and assign the byte array to the report field.

Comment: let me clear  first u r not using parameter in rdlc report

Comment: sorry but couldn't perform

Comment: I tried with parameter, but then after no success I removed them. Please take care, about the errors in the InnerException when getting `An error occurred during local report processing.`

Comment: your code was correct but i couldn't apply in my project

Comment: Restart in your project with a very simple Report in the ReportViewer, no Image, no ReportParameter, just only one textbox to verify everything else with the Report is configured correctly.